# IntelliJ cannot see classes of dependency

Tags: java, spring, maven, intellij-idea

I have two maven projects and I wanted to use one as a dependency to another. Now I built the project1 with `mvn clean install` and added it to project2 like this:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
        <artifactId>project1</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

I can see this jar and all of its classes in my project2 external libraries folder. Let's say this project has `MyClass` class. When I try type in a name of this class, IntelliJ shows it in the context menu so it is aware of its existance. However as soon as I try to instantiate `com.foo.MyClass` IntelliJ says that it `cannot resolve symbol foo`. I am quite new to Spring so I am not really sure if this is a problem with my code or some kind of IntelliJ bug.

Comment: Could you please ensure the package `com.foo` exists inside your dependency `project1` ? Please note that Maven `groupId` is not related to your packages inside the dependency.

Comment: It does exist in the original `project1` and in the `project2` external libraries.

Comment: Well, that's you're problem I think.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: You used the wrong package for the class `MyClass`. The package of the class `MyClass` is not related to the `groupId` of the Maven dependency.

Comment: I don't think I follow your answer. In my `project1` I have a package `com.foo` that contains MyClass. So if I added this `project1` jar as a dependency to `project2` (regardless to the `groupId` of the dependency) I should be able to call that class by `com.foo.MyClass`. Am I correct?